# Select Stored Procedure Outputs On-the-Fly (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, return

I am trying to pass an output parameter from a stored procedure into another stored procedure.  The parent needs to pass a parameter into the child.

Can I return the output on-the-fly in a select statement like this?

If not, what is a good way to approach this problem?

Stored Procedure (Child)

```
@uid int,
@result nvarchar(max) output

as

begin select @result = stuff((
  select 
  'cid' = cid

  from db

  for xml path('')
  ), 
  1, 
  1, 
  '<'
)

return

end
```

Stored Procedure (Parent)

```
 select
 'id'         = uid,
 'result'     = (exec db.dbo.table uid, @result output) 
 from table
```

Here I am trying to pass in a `uid` from the parents select statement, and pass it into another stored procedure, and return the result in a select.

Comment: You have the right idea but you have to insert the results from the SP into a table then select from that table, here is a good example:  https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/05/27/sql-server-how-to-insert-data-from-stored-procedure-to-table-2-different-methods/

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're after, however, the fact that you have a `EXEC` statement in your `SELECT` make me think otherwise.

```
CREATE PROC Child @uid int, @result nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT AS

    SELECT @result = STUFF((SELECT cid AS cid
                            FROM db
                            --Should there be a WHERE here?
                            FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,1,N'<');
GO

CREATE PROC Parent @uid int AS

    DECLARE @result nvarchar(MAX);

    EXEC Child @uid, @result OUTPUT;

    SELECT @uid UID, @result AS Result;
GO
```

That is more of a literal copy of what you have in your question though. It might be that this is more what you're after with an inline-table function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Child (@uid int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

    SELECT  STUFF((SELECT cid AS cid
                   FROM db
                   --Should there be a WHERE here?
                   FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,1,N'<') AS cid;
GO

CREATE PROC Parent @uid int AS


    SELECT @uid UID,
           C.cid
    FROM [Table]
         CROSS APPLY dbo.Child(@uid) C
GO
```

Like I said in the comments, it seems we're missing a WHERE or something here.